# Can Not Access RESTful service in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was trying to develop a Spring Boot application with REST API which would send mails as per supplied credential via JSON. But the problem is I could not access the API by hitting from URL via Postman tool.

Here I should mention that I am not doing any Database Table operation with this very small application. The purpose of this application to  send mails once a proper JSON is received with all required  credentials.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mailService")
public class MailController{
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;
    
    @PostMapping("/sendMail")
    public ResponseEntity<Long>  sendMail(@RequestBody MailPojo pojo){
        System.out.println("POST Request ....");
        MailResponse resp = mailService.sendMail(pojo);
        
        return new ResponseEntity(resp, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
}
```

MailPojo contains the required credential values which are required to send mail.

```
public class MailPojo {
    
    private String smtpServer;  
    private String userName;    
    private String password;
    private String smtpPort;    
    private String emailFrom;  
    private String emailTo;     
    private String emailCC;    
    private String emailSubject;    
    private String emailText;  
    ...
    ......

}
```

MailService is supposed to do the actual job. It contains the mechanism to send mail.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
    
    @Override
    public MailResponse sendMail(MailPojo pojo) {
        
        String srvrResp = "";
        String retn = "";
        String SMTP_SERVER = pojo.getSmtpServer();    
        final String USERNAME =  pojo.getUserName();  
        final String PASSWORD = pojo.getPassword();   
        String TLS = "Y";
        String smtpPort = pojo.getSmtpPort();         
        String EMAIL_FROM = pojo.getEmailFrom();      
        String EMAIL_TO = pojo.getEmailTo();          
        String EMAIL_CC = pojo.getEmailCC();         
        String EMAIL_SUBJECT = pojo.getEmailSubject();   
        String EMAIL_TEXT = pojo.getEmailText();         

        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER); // optional, defined in SMTPTransport
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);    // default port 25 (TLS)
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL Port
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory Class
        
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, auth);

        System.out.println("Session created");
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {

            ...
            ....
            ......

            t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

            System.out.println("Response: " + t.getLastServerResponse());
            srvrResp = t.getLastServerResponse();
            
            retn ="SUCCESS";
            t.close();

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            retn = "FAILED";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        .....
        ........

        return respObj;     
    }

   
}
```

On running the spring boot application the console shows below lines -

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.12)

2023-06-11 22:53:10.535  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] in.issac.mailsend.MailsendApplication    : Starting MailsendApplication using Java 17.0.7 on DESKTOP-QU763SD with PID 3048 (F:\STS_Workspace\mailsend\target\classes started by Jayanta Pramanik in F:\STS_Workspace\mailsend)
2023-06-11 22:53:10.551  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] in.issac.mailsend.MailsendApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-11 22:53:10.680  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-06-11 22:53:10.680  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-06-11 22:53:12.816  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-11 22:53:12.838  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-11 22:53:12.839  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.75]
2023-06-11 22:53:12.969  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-11 22:53:12.971  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2289 ms
2023-06-11 22:53:13.927  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-06-11 22:53:14.017  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-11 22:53:14.055  INFO 3048 --- [  restartedMain] in.issac.mailsend.MailsendApplication    : Started MailsendApplication in 4.256 seconds (JVM running for 5.13)
```

Now my question is how can I access the API ?
I tried to access it as below from postman tool but it was failed to call the API.

```
**http://localhost:8080/mailsend/mailService/sendMail**
```

Anyone here who can suggest how the API could be called successfully ?

Comment: your controller says it should be `POST localhost:8080/mailService/sendMail`

Comment: did you try removing mailsend from your url ?

Comment: I tried to access after removing "mailsend" from URL but no luck. Any more idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You must call the URL

```
POST http://localhost:8080/mailService/sendMail
```

reconfirm your MailController

Comment: I removed the mailsend word and still I could not call the API from postman. Now URL looks like : POST  http://localhost:8080/mailService/sendMail   Any more suggestion please ?

Comment: Can I get `Http Status Code` or `Error Log`?